# What cognitive service do I need to select in order to be able to make Azure VM API calls?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-api-management, azure-cognitive-services

I need to provide subscriptionId to Api request, but I get "InvalidSubscriptionId error".

I found out that subscription key needs to be 32-digit hexadecimal number, without hyphens, and one that I provide is with hyphens and letters. 
I saw on the web that the key that I need is under Cognitive Services.

My question is what Cognitive Service should I choose to obtain that key and  to be able to make Azure API calls for creating, starting, stopping virtual machines?

Answer (score 0):

You *do not* need a cognitive service to create, start or stop a Virtual Machine. With Cognitive Services you can ...

> Infuse your apps, websites and bots with intelligent algorithms to see, hear, speak, understand and interpret your user needs through natural methods of communication. Transform your business with AI today.

What (I think) you're looking for is how to use the Azure REST API. [Getting Started with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) might be an interesting starting point for you.

If you're looking for something a bit more specific, find documentation on [Virtual machines - Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/start) here.

*TIP: click the 'Try It' button, it helps you craft a request to start a VM.*